# how to call to javascript function using php?

Tags: php, javascript

This question is more complex than we think.

I need to call a function in javascript from php if some condition is met.

The php code and the javascript function are in the same file.

I don't need to generate code of java script function because it is not effective to be done in a function with parameters and I also need to make changes to the contents of the function.

How do I call `CreateSVG();` line 58 in the php code?
many thanks.

My full file looks like below:

```
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    </script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


</head>
<body>


    <div id="frame_shape">&nbsp;
        <div id="main">
            <h2>OOP Class Demo using PHP</h2>
            <h2>Drawing shape usinig user parameteres.</h2>
            <p>
            Please enter two numbers to calculate the area of rectangle or tringle and press submit...
            <p>
                <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?>">
                    <br>width<input type=text name='width'>
                    <br>height<input type=text name='height'>
                    <h2>select shape</h2>
                    <input type="radio" name="shape" value="Rectangle" /> Rectangle
                    <br><input type="radio" name="shape" value="Tringle" /> Tringle
                    <br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit Form"><br>
                </form>
        <br/><br/>
        </div>
        <div id="retangle">
            <div id="svgContainer"></div>
        </div>
        <div id="Tringle"></div>
            <div id="contener">
                <?php
                 echo("<br>");
                        if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
                                if (!empty($_POST['shape'])) {
                                  if ($_POST['shape'] === 'Rectangle') { 
                                      // create object of rectangle and calculate it is area
                  $rect = new Rectangle ($_POST['width'], $_POST['height']);
                  echo 'rectangle of this size would have the area of ', $rect->GetArea(), "<br />";
                  //echo '<script type="text/javascript">', 'CreateSVG();', '</script>';
                  echo '<script>CreateSVG();</script>';

                                  }
                                    else if ($_POST['shape'] === 'Tringle'){
                                              // create object of tringle and calculate it is area by extends
                  $tri = new Triangle ($_POST['width'], $_POST['height']);
                  echo 'triangle of this sizes would have the area of ', $tri->GetArea();
                                         }
                                }
                       }
                ?>
            </div>
    </div>

<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    function CreateSVG(){
            var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
            var boxWidth = <?php echo $_POST['width'];?>;
            var boxHeight = <?php echo $_POST['height'];?>;
            alert(boxWidth + ' ' + boxHeight);
            var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
            svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
            svgElem.style.display = "block";

            var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
            svgElem.appendChild (g);
            g.setAttributeNS (null, 'transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,300)');

                // draw linear gradient
            var defs = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "defs");
            var grad = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "linearGradient");
            grad.setAttributeNS (null, "id", "gradient");
            grad.setAttributeNS (null, "x1", "0%");
            grad.setAttributeNS (null, "x2", "0%");
            grad.setAttributeNS (null, "y1", "100%");
            grad.setAttributeNS (null, "y2", "0%");
            var stopTop = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "stop");
            stopTop.setAttributeNS (null, "offset", "0%");
            stopTop.setAttributeNS (null, "stop-color", "#ff0000");
            grad.appendChild (stopTop);
            var stopBottom = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "stop");
            stopBottom.setAttributeNS (null, "offset", "100%");
            stopBottom.setAttributeNS (null, "stop-color", "#0000ff");
            grad.appendChild (stopBottom);
            defs.appendChild (grad);
            g.appendChild (defs);

                // draw borders
            var coords = "M 0, 0";
            coords += " l 0, 300";
            coords += " l 300, 0";
            coords += " l 0, -300";
            coords += " l -300, 0";

            var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "path");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke', "#000000");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-width', 10);
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-linejoin', "round");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'd', coords);
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'fill', "url(#gradient)");
            path.setAttributeNS (null, 'opacity', 1.0);
            g.appendChild (path);

            var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgContainer");
            svgContainer.appendChild (svgElem); 
    }




});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Remove your function from Document.ready(){ } and put it outside of it may be it can help

Comment: I just want to call to function CreateSVG(); which know how to draw the shape according the user parameter the function know to do that but .I need to call it not to echo it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the CreateSVG() Javascript function into the HEAD region, and remove the document.Ready syntax so the header reads ...

```
<?php
require_once("includes/initialize.php");
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>OOP Class Demo using PHP by yossi levi.</title>
    <script src="http://www.centerwow.com/gotemp/gotemptics.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function CreateSVG() {
             /* Add the existing function here */
        }
    </script>
    <style>
        body {  font-size:20px; background:#00CCFF; }
        button { margin:2px; }
        /* Styles removed for simplicity */
     </style>
</head>
```

In your method you are trying to call a function that isn't yet defined.

Answer (score 1):

Following example will help you:

```
 <?php
     ----
     ----

    if (< SOME CONDITION >) {
    echo "<script language=javascript>CreateSVG()</script>";
    }

    ---- 
    ---- 
   ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

put `<?php if (condition) :?>` block between this function

```
<?php if (condition): ?>
    <script>

    $(document).ready(function() {

        function CreateSVG(){
                var xmlns = "http://www.w3.org/2000/svg";
                var boxWidth = <?php echo $_POST['width'];?>;
                var boxHeight = <?php echo $_POST['height'];?>;
                alert(boxWidth + ' ' + boxHeight);
                var svgElem = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "svg");
                svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "viewBox", "0 0 " + boxWidth + " " + boxHeight);
                svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "width", boxWidth);
                svgElem.setAttributeNS (null, "height", boxHeight);
                svgElem.style.display = "block";

                var g = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "g");
                svgElem.appendChild (g);
                g.setAttributeNS (null, 'transform', 'matrix(1,0,0,-1,0,300)');

                    // draw linear gradient
                var defs = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "defs");
                var grad = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "linearGradient");
                grad.setAttributeNS (null, "id", "gradient");
                grad.setAttributeNS (null, "x1", "0%");
                grad.setAttributeNS (null, "x2", "0%");
                grad.setAttributeNS (null, "y1", "100%");
                grad.setAttributeNS (null, "y2", "0%");
                var stopTop = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "stop");
                stopTop.setAttributeNS (null, "offset", "0%");
                stopTop.setAttributeNS (null, "stop-color", "#ff0000");
                grad.appendChild (stopTop);
                var stopBottom = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "stop");
                stopBottom.setAttributeNS (null, "offset", "100%");
                stopBottom.setAttributeNS (null, "stop-color", "#0000ff");
                grad.appendChild (stopBottom);
                defs.appendChild (grad);
                g.appendChild (defs);

                    // draw borders
                var coords = "M 0, 0";
                coords += " l 0, 300";
                coords += " l 300, 0";
                coords += " l 0, -300";
                coords += " l -300, 0";

                var path = document.createElementNS (xmlns, "path");
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke', "#000000");
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-width', 10);
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'stroke-linejoin', "round");
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'd', coords);
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'fill', "url(#gradient)");
                path.setAttributeNS (null, 'opacity', 1.0);
                g.appendChild (path);

                var svgContainer = document.getElementById ("svgContainer");
                svgContainer.appendChild (svgElem); 
        }




    });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert this code at the end of the script tag...

```
<?php          
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['shape'])) {
            if ($_POST['shape'] === 'Rectangle') { 
                  echo "CreateSVG();";
            }
        }
    }
?>
```

Like this... Showing a part of the code...

```
$("#Tringle").text($("#Tringle").width() +' '+ $("#Tringle").height() );
$("#Tringle").text($("#Tringle").width() +' '+ $("#Tringle").height() +', left: '+ $("#Tringle").position().left +' top: '+ $("#Tringle").position().top);

<?php          
    if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
        if (!empty($_POST['shape'])) {
            if ($_POST['shape'] === 'Rectangle') { 
                  echo "CreateSVG();";
            }
        }
    }
?>

});
</script>
```